# How do I validate a checkout form in React?

Tags: reactjs, forms, validation, jsx

I am trying to implement a checkout form in React. The form has 4 fields in all: Name, CC Number, CC expiration and CVV. I am using a library that validates each field on unfocus. The validation is triggered by the validationCallback method which takes 3 arguments: field, status, and message. I'd like to key off of the status for each input and only allow submit once each status === true. Here is my code.

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      nameOnCard: '',
      errorMessage: '',
      showLoaderForPayment: '',
      collectJs: null,
      token: null,
      isPaymentRequestCalled: false,
      showErrorModal: false,
      paymentErrorText: '',
      disabled: true,
    };
  }
```

I have a disabled property in my state which I'm initially setting to true.

```
validationCallback: (field, status, message) => {
          if (status) {
            this.setState({ errorMessage: '' });
          } else {
            let fieldName = '';
            switch (field) {
              case 'ccnumber':
                fieldName = 'Credit Card';
                break;
              case 'ccexp':
                fieldName = 'Expire Date';
                break;
              case 'cvv':
                fieldName = 'Security Code';
                break;
              default:
                fieldName = 'A';
            }
            if (message === 'Field is empty') {
              this.setState({ errorMessage: `${fieldName} ${message}` });
            } else {
              this.setState({ errorMessage: `${message}` });
            }
          }
        },
```

In the above method, I'd like to set disabled to false if each of the field's status===true... Below is the button which I'm setting to be the value of this.state.disabled.

```
<button
                className="continueBtn disabled"
                disabled={this.state.disabled}
                onClick={this.handleCardSubmit}
              >
                <span className="fa fa-lock" />
                &nbsp; Pay $
                {selectedPayment.amount}
              </button>
```

I hope this is enough of the code to help with the issue. I can provide more of the file if need be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what i understand, you want to set the button to NOT DISABLED if all the fields are filled properly, i.e. all status are true.
What you can do is maintain a boolean array for each field and update the status in that array, i.e. initialize an array of length = no. of fields (in your case 3) and set all values as false. False depicts that the field hasn't been validated.

```
this.state = {
  statusArray = [false, false, false] // For as many fields
}
```

Then in validationCallback, set the index as true or false for that field i.e. if the 2nd field status is returned true by your validation library, set statusArray as [false, true, false].
The form will only be validated if all 3 of the values become true. So you can iterate over the array and check if array has all 3 values as true. or you can use the logical AND operator which returns true only if all values are true(the approach which i use below).
For the button,

```
<button disabled={this.checkDisable()}>

checkDisable = () => {
  let temp = this.state.statusArray;
  let answer = true;
  for(int i=0;i<temp.length;i++)
    answer = answer && temp[i];
  return answer;  // Only returns true if all 3 values are true
}
```

I hope you get it now.

Comment: Are you suggesting to hard code the statusArray with false fields by default? I have 3 fields

Comment: Yes, hard coding them will initialize them as false and help out with your use case

Comment: Is it possible you could elaborate more with your answer? It doesn't make alot of sense.

Comment: I have edited it. If you dont understand still, can u explain exactly which part?

Comment: Thanks.. I was able to get it working with your solution above.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check 2 things, has the form been touched and are there any errors. I don't know what library you are using but most likely it has a property touched in it, if not add an `onFocus`  to each input field and a touched property in your state. You don't really need a disabled property in your state since its a computed value. Just check on every render if the form has been touched and if there are any errors.

```
state = {
...,
touched: false,
...
}

handleFocus = () => this.setState({touched: true}) 

render(){
  const disabled = !!(this.state.touched && this.state.errorCode)
  return(
  ...
  <input onFocus={this.handleFocus} ... />
  ...
  <button disabled={disabled}
  )
}
```

EDIT:

```
state = {
...
validInputs: []
}

validationCallback: (field, status, message) => {
          if (status) {
            this.setState((state) => ({ errorMessage: '', validInputs: [... new Set([...state.validInputs, field])] }));
          } else {
    ...
    render(){
    const disabled = this.state.length < inputs.length // the number of the input fields
    return(
      ...
      <button disabled={disabled} > 
      ...
    )
```

Comment: I'm using a library from a vendor. Each input field is being validated on their end. Once each field is out of focus their is a callback that's sent to them and they validate the field. On each validation they return a status which is a boolean. I only want the submit button to be enabled if the status of each button is true. There are three inputs. These inputs are ccnumber, ccexp and cvv.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. In this case, I would suggest you go with similar to PiNaKa30's answer. You could add one more field to state, such as `validInputs`. In the validation Callback function you will add the input field name to `validInputs` array, if it doesn't exist. 
 On rerender check if the `validInputs` length is the same as the length of the input